# Windows 10 Creator's Update Autofill Bug

Tags: autofill

I just had a Windows 10 "Creators Update" on my work laptop (can't go back to previous version). Now one of my macros is broken. This macro is very important and central to much of the work I do. I use it to create complex multiple entity journal entries for a major world-wide company. The macro worked perfectly for over a year and it perplexes me on how there could possibly be an error with the countless hours of testing I've done.

The code that breaks is below. The line that breaks is the autofill line

```
    fromrangeb = "H5:Q" & (4 + count_from)

Sheet3.Range("H5:Q5").AutoFill Destination:=Range(fromrangeb), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

The error I get is "Run-time error '1004': AutoFill method of Range class failed.

I do not see how there could be an error and the variable fromrangeb is declared as a string and has the value H5:Q34 when I hover over it in the debug window. Furthermore, the button works perfectly fine if I copy the macro button to Sheet3 and push it. If I specifically telling the macro to run off sheet three in the code why do I need to place the macro button on sheet3?

I want this code to work on sheet1 because this is the sheet everyone uses to fill out the template.

What could possibly cause this to occur? Is anyone else having this issue?

If I write the simplest macro as show below it bugs out unless my workbook is on sheet1 then it works fine (I have the value 1 in cell H7).

```
Sub Macro1()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H7").AutoFill Destination:=Range("H7:H20"), Type:=xlFillSeries

End Sub
```

When I specifically call out the sheet in the code I should NOT have to be on the sheet for the code to run. I've written many VBA programs and this screams as some sort of bug. I couldn't find anyone else with this issue yet online.

Am I crazy or is this a bug via the newest Win 10 Creator's Update?

This macro has simultaneously stopped working on half a dozen coworker's computers and they all went through the update. I have a work around (by running the macro from the hidden sheet 3) but I don't want to permanently change my well distributed macro. Does anyone know if this bug will be fixed?